# Vaadin - Multiple TabSheet Layout

Tags: java, tabs, vaadin

I have few Vaadin tabs one of them is displaying an table and some buttons, another one displays an Hierarchical Vaadin tree and has an custom search Box. I have set the size of my tabs to H:420px W:250px so they have the same size, if the table gets too big or the tree to long I get an scrollbar (that’s what I wanted) the problem is that the other components like the search Box and the buttons are being forced down at the bottom of the layout so if I want to access the buttons/ search Box I have to scroll all the way down so I can use the component I want. I have tried to add an second layout only for the components but it didn’t help:-/ here’s what I have tried so far:

```
TabSheet tabs = new TabSheet();
tabs.setWidth("250");
tabs.setHeight("420");

VerticalLayout lyTab = new VerticalLayout();
tabOne = tabs.addTab(lyTab, "Tab One", null);
//added an extra layout for the Buttons :
HorizontalLayout  lyButton = new HorizontalLayout();
lyButton.addComponent(applyButton);
lyButton.addComponent(selectAll);
lyTab.addComponent(lyButton);
```

my idea was to add an second layout to the tabSheet so i can fix its position so it cant move but it didnt work . any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly here is how to do it with a Table:

```
VerticalLayout tab = new VerticalLayout();
tab.setSizeFull();

Table table = new Table();
table.setSizeFull();
tab.addComponent(table);
tab.setExpandRatio(table, 1);

HorizontalLayout buttons = new HorizontalLayout();
buttons.addComponent(new Button());
buttons.addComponent(new Button());
tab.addComponent(buttons);

Tab tabOne = tabs.addTab(tab, "Tab One", null);
```

In this case, the Table is full sized and shows scrollbars when needed.

For a Tree, replace the Table part from above code with:

```
Panel panel = new Panel();
panel.setSizeFull();
panel.getContent().setSizeUndefined();
tab.addComponent(panel);
tab.setExpandRatio(panel, 1);

Tree tree = new Tree();
tree.setSizeUndefined();
panel.addComponent(tree);
```

Here the Tree is not able to show scrollbars so we wrap it inside a full sized Panel that shows scrollbars when needed.

Answer (score 0):

I was still experiencing similar issues in Vaadin 7.4.8 and was able to make it work.

1 - The first thing I made sure was that parent components(in my case I had two VerticalLayout's being added one into another) had setSizeFull(). They are being added to a View. In my case, I forgot to set it on a Class that extends VerticalLayout and Implements View, called by navigator.

2 - The other important detail is that the tabSheet - on which tabs were added with addTab(component) must also have a setSizeFull() being set, so that the tab takes all unused space, especially on towards the bottom.

2.1 - Added a setExpandRatio(tabSheet, 1) so that it is being shifted towards the top.

3 - Now, for a component(VerticalLayout) that is being added to a tabSheet using addTab(component), I had two components added to it, one is a HorizontalLayout and the second one is a VerticalLayout.

So I made sure that :

- it had setSizeFull
- setExpandRatio(HorizontalLayout, .5f);
- setExpandRatio(VerticalLayout, .5f);